# What is the best way to manage roles in ActiveDirectory for ASP.NET Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, active-directory, active-directory-group

Summary:

I am authenticating users with Active Directory for an INTRAnet website for users on our domain. What is the best way to handle permissions (Admin, Supervisor, Reader)?

Environment:

I am using ASP.NET C# (.NET Framework 4.5) website with Visual Studio 2012 with IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

My Question in detail:

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle permissions. I can probably get Role(s) added to active directory for my project. The project is called Eagle. I was wondering if I should get 3 roles added to AD and call them EagleAdmin, EagleSupervisor, and EagleReader) or if it if should create my permissions within SQL Server for the users (and if so, what's the best way to do this?).

FYI: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28546/Active-Directory-Roles-Provider)  is the brilliant code project that helped me figure out the AD authentication!

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the classes in the namespaces System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

You can use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext class to get access to the desired active directory and make use of the methods of UserPrincipal to get the user information and roles using GroupPrincipal.

```
using(var context=new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"YOURDOMAINNAME")
{
    using(var user=UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,"usernametosearchfor")
     {
var userGroupsOfCurrentUser=user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
     }
}
```

Please mark as answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm doing that already, my question: What's the best way to set up the access structure? Should I create 3 roles in AD for EagleAdmin, EagleSupervisor, EagleReader, or should I handle the different permission levels within SQL Server? (and if so, what's the best way to do that?)

Comment: That depends on which one you prefer. Both will work. If you physically need to organize users to handle the roles, then go with the Active Directory based grouping approach. If you will handle the role in code, then you can pick the DB oriented way.

Comment: Thanks Ananthan - I'd mark yours as the answer, but I'm not sure I can do that from a comment. Thanks. I was excited to use the roles within AD but the more I think about it, it's overkill and makes maintenance more difficult.

Comment: Then I think you should probably go with SQL Server based role management.